# Can't access docker containers when there more than 2 containers

Tags: java, docker

Under Windows 10 I have a docker container `app` which is `FROM openjdk:8` with java server inside. Java server starts on port 8080 and container exposes this port in`Dockerfile`.

When I running 2 instances of this container and bind them to different ports on host machine, I can access them by same IP (VirtualBox Host-Only Network) with different ports. When I run 3rd instance - all instances become inaccessible over this IP, but containers and applications inside still running.
When I stop recently started 3rd container - the first 2 containers becomes accessible over that IP again in some time.

I tried to connect those containers to different networks (bridge and newly created one) but this didn't help.

Starting containers with commands:

`docker run --rm --name first_instance -v repo:/volume -it -p 8080:8080 app`

`docker run --rm --name second_instance --volumes-from first_instance -it -p 8081:8080 app`

`docker run --rm --name third_instance --volumes-from first_instance -it -p 8082:8080 app`

Dockerfile is: (Docker Version: 17.03.1-ce)

```
FROM openjdk:8

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

ADD root/deployment/. /root/deployment
ADD root/installation/. /root/installation
ADD scripts /app

# Make port 8080 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 8080

# Define environment variable
ENV INSTALLED_DIR="/root/installation/"
ENV DEPLOYED_DIR="/root/deployment/"
ENV JAVA_HOME="${INSTALLED_DIR}/java"
ENV INSTALLED_JARS_DIR="${INSTALLED_DIR}/lib"
ENV DEPLOYED_JARS_DIR="${DEPLOYED_DIR}/webapps/bin/WEB-INF/lib"
ENV DEPLOYED_CLASSES_DIR="${DEPLOYED_DIR}/webapps/bin/WEB-INF/classes"

CMD $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -cp 
"$INSTALLED_JARS_DIR/*:$DEPLOYED_JARS_DIR/*:$DEPLOYED_CLASSES_DIR/*" \
-DAdminPassword=xxxxxxx -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties \
org.flycaw.platform.Runner setup.properties setup-create-new.properties \
    && /root/deployment/wrapper/APP start \
    && /bin/bash
```

I want to figure out why I can't run more than 2 instances of the application and be able to access them via IP:PORT combination.

Comment: Please send your code, as much as you've typed. We'll deal with this sorcery.

Comment: You are lacking a lot of information. Please add the commands used to start and stop the containers, the relevant `Dockerfile`, Docker version, how Docker was installed.

Comment: I've added a ```Dockerfile``` and commands that I used to run containers.